# How to show description for Custom Function Parameters in Officejs

Tags: office-js

We are using Excel add-in Custom Functions with Batching using OfficeJS and below are the clarifications.

1. For any new custom functions we were able to show with description for the function selected in Excel.
2. But for the parameters used in the functions could not show description for respective parameters when
   selected the same. 
    .

Based on below sample, it is not showing number1 as description when entering num1 parameter.

**Sample Custom Functions code**

```
/**
 * Sample Custom addition function
 * @CustomFunction Sampleaddition Sample.add
 * @param num1[][] number1
 * @param [num2]  number2
 * @param [num3] 
 */
```

Kindly let me know if anything missing on above sample or any other details wanted further.

**Tried below sample code also but still description of parameters are not displayed both in online version and desktop version.**

```
/**
 * Calculates the sum of the specified numbers
 * @customfunction
 * @param first First number.
 * @param second Second number.
 * @param [third] Third number to add. If omitted, third = 0.
 * @returns The sum of the numbers.
 */
function add(first: number, second: number, third?: number): number {
  if (third === null) {
    third = 0;
  }
  return first + second + third;
}
```

Comment: Hi team, any update please?

Comment: Hi team,,,,any of you the team looking into this issue?...

Comment: Hi team.. Any update or anything missing in my question?

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this format below. You could check if the description is generated the metadata file (you can reference document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/custom-functions-json#associating-function-names-with-json-metadata)
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the update. Also I have tried sample code which updated in main request. In that scenario also parameters of description not showing. Kindly let me know anything required...

Comment: I am able to see Customfunctions.json file where description generated for the custom functions used.

Comment: Hi team, any help or finding?

Comment: Sorry for the misleading. The parameter description could not show... The function description can show when user select functions. I will submit this request to product team. Currently you may need to clarify more in function description if it can help.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation ruoyingl...also what does mean this "{number} first First Number" in custom functions First Number...because in all example i could see this implementation but it is not showing in intellisense Excel cells.....Can you please confirm when this could be released?

Comment: @ruoyingl.. Can you please confirm on previous clarification so that we can keep be informed our users...

Comment: @ruoyingl....then showing parameter description when it available with any tentative date?

Comment: @ruoying... Any update please to show descriptions for function parameters?

Comment: Sorry @Murugaananth but showing parameter description is a new feature in custom function and currently we don't have any estimated timeline for it.